# Relationships window - how to show the table from the edge?

Tags: ms-access

After big work on the project I've encountered the problem with the relationship window. Some tables are situated beyond the margin of the window:

[image]

That's not too comfortable, I'm addicted to this window using. This problem is shown on versions of MS Access till 2019 and I have no idea how to show this tables. I can not remove them because there are no hotkeys to select another table and show the popup menu.

Comment: Never seen this. Perhaps this link can help https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/528324-releationship-diagram-goes-haywire

Comment: If nothing else helps, "Clear Layout" and "All Relationships" from the toolbar will bring them back... but you'll have to re-create your layout from scratch. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can not remove them because there are no hotkeys to select another table and show the popup menu.*

Actually there is: select any table, press `TAB` until no visible table is selected, i.e. one of the invisible table is selected.

Press `Del` to remove it. Repeat until you got them all.

Then click "All Relationships" from the toolbar to bring the missing tables back.

Comment: thanks. Never used hotkeys for Relationship window before.

Answer (score 0):

My relationships pane has scrollbars.
I assume from the question that yours does not.
Further I assume that you have tried saving, closing, compact and repair etc?
suggestion:
Try adding a random table, slightly off the top (or bottom) edge of the relationships window and see if the scroll bar pops up.

Answer (score 0):

The only code I've encountered, that deals with the window of the relations, is the old code from *Stephen Lebans*:

[SaveRelationshipView](http://lebans.com/saverelationshipview.htm)

Most likely, some x-coordinates have become negative, but either the code should be able to correct that, or you might be able to use it to read and correct the values manually.